# Как закрыть Activity?

Tags: java, android-sdk

При вызове метода `onItemClick` нужно закрыть текущую `Activity`.
В `closeActivity()` через `this.finish()` почему-то `Activity` закрыть нельзя.
Для этого я создал еще один метод, в котором пытаюсь ее закрыть. Но в результате `Activity` переходит в "спящий режим" и остается в стеке `Activity`.
В чём ошибка?

Код методов (сразу с привязкой слушателя к `ListView`):

```
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SelectDictionary.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        closeActivity();
    }
});

private void closeActivity() {
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: использовать this.finish() внутри onItemClick нельзя, т.к. внутри этого метода this не ссылается на context. Уберите this и просто вызывайте finish()

Comment: Да нет, тут this роли не играет. Надо просто флаг добавить, как в ответе ниже написано.

Comment: Юрий, попробую. С флагами кода больше, а с finish должно сработать. А почему на this не ссылается? Все-таки метод в Activity, она никуда не пропала!

Comment: Я в комменте отвечал не на весь вопрос, а на его часть про this.finish только. А this в вашем коде ссылается на объект AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, а не на активити. оттого и ошибка.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Насколько я вижу, метод `сloseActivity()` хоть и вызывается из класса адаптера, но находится в активити и `this` в данном случае ссылается на класс `Activity`

Comment: @pavlofff. Насколько я понял автора он пытался вызвать `this.finish()` в теле метода `onItemClick()`, коий является реализацией метода интерфейса, имплементированного в анонимном классе, переданном в качестве параметра методу `setOnItemClickListener()`. У него это не вышло и он создал в активити метод `closeActivity()` в коем и смог использовать `this.finish()`, т.к. в . `closeActivity()` this - это ссылка на активити, а в `onItemClick()` this это ссылка на анонимный класс, реализующий интерфейс.`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, только вот closeActivity() не сработало!

Comment: @bukashka101, а причём здесь это? Я указал только на одну из проблем, поднятых в вопросе. Если б я отвечал на саму суть вопроса я бы это в ответе делал, а не в комменте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я понял. Кстати, finish() не работает. Придется разбираться в флагах...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, уже психанул и назначил Activity обработчиков и закрыл через ``this.finish()``, но оно НЕ РАБОТАЕТ... Будет у меня не закрытое Activity...

Comment: @bukashka101 смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15393947/3212712) и [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

1. В манифесте, в объявлении вашей `MainActivity` добавляем

   > android:noHistory="true"
2. Теперь покидая эту активити (любым способом, в т.ч. запуская новую) она сама вызывает свой finish() и удаляется из стека активити

Answer (score 5):

В принципе, да, `Activity` так устроена, что по умолчанию она засыпает, когда другая стартует. Но можно добавить флаг в `Intent`, чтобы это поменять:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SelectDictionary.this, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
closeActivity();
```

Comment: А что такое флаг? :)

Comment: Ну типа какой-то параметр "да/нет" для настройки.

Comment: Не работает.. :(

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(ThisActivity.this, intent);
```

Comment: Вы немного запоздали :)...

Comment: @bukashka101 Дело в том, что ответы даются не лично вам, а всем, у кого появится аналогичная проблема и чем больше ответов, тем лучше

Answer (score -2):

в конце обработчика напиши эту команду и все

```
super.finish();
```